# How to use Twilio APIs in Android?

Tags: android, twilio

How can I use Twilio APIs to send and receive messages on Android?Can I code in Android Studio itself to integrate these APIs?

Comment: you cant just use twilio directly in android you have to implement it on a server end. and then request you server to perform the required action

Answer (score 0):

Anurag, this post by my colleague Marcos details the best practices for [sending messages](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/sending-messages) for Android.

https://www.twilio.com/blog/2016/05/how-to-send-an-sms-from-android.html

As Tabish from comments suggests, we implement our backend server in using the [Java helper library](https://www.twilio.com/docs/libraries/java).

```
public class SMSBackend {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
       get("/", (req, res) -> "Hello, World");

       TwilioRestClient client = new TwilioRestClient("YOUR_TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID", "YOUR_TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN");

       post("/sms", (req, res) -> {
           String body = req.queryParams("Body");
           String to = req.queryParams("To");
           String from = "YOUR_TWILIO_PHONE_NUMBER";

           Map<String, String> callParams = new HashMap<>();
           callParams.put("To", to);
           callParams.put("From", from);
           callParams.put("Body", body);
           Sms message = client.getAccount().getSmsFactory().create(callParams);

           return message.getSid();
       });
   }
}
```

Using OkHttp, you can then make http requests from your app to the Java backend.